# ubuntu 16.04 launcher icon size gsettings command line

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, icons, gsettings

I know how to change the appearance and size of the launcher icons via GUI; however, in 14.04LTS I used

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size 18
```

To adjust the size and it worked via command line.  My problem is that doesn't seem to work in 16.04 because dconf tools aren't installed.

I would like to use the native gsettings and change it that way.  I found this for the launcher move from left to bottom

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom.
```

But I can't find anything to adjust the icon size

Suggestions

Answer (score 0):

That one is really tricky (I had to look at the code of unity-control-center to find it). It is

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size <SIZE>
```

Hope that helps.