# Saving and restoring Ubuntu settings for fresh Ubuntu installations

Tags: backup, settings, system-settings

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS whose GUI allows customization. These include

1. Launcher Icon Size
2. Behaviour of the launcher (hides, size of launcher, reveal sensitivity)
3. System Language
4. My dual display settings, their positioning
5. My items docked on the launcher

Basically, all such settings I applied to the system via GUI for my ease.

I want some sort of a hack to back up such settings to a file and reapply them when I reinstall the OS.

Comment: Generic answer: each of these settings can be set through command line. 1 and 2 are done with `gsettings`, 3 is editing 2 text files, 4 and 5 are probably also text files. So put the commands to edit these files in a script and save that script. Execute when needed. AskUbuntu expects 1 question per topic and there are 5 here. 1+2 are likely already answered. 3 and 4 probably also will have an answer. 5 is probably about setting a .desktop file you can store somewhere so you can reapply; will also have a topic+answer on AU.

Comment: Icon size: https://askubuntu.com/questions/809914/ubuntu-16-04-launcher-icon-size-gsettings-command-line  2: probably https://askubuntu.com/a/132394/15811 but you will get the gist: `gsettings set`, you need the `key`, and a `value` to change a setting. Language: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133318/how-do-i-change-the-language-via-a-terminal (related: keyboard: https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line/209598 )

Comment: AFAIK they are all config files stored in `~/.config/`. So if you copy over your home directory, or at least that (hidden) folder, you should see most(all?) your settings restored.

Comment: @Robert Riedl This is exactly what I wanted. Please post this as asnwer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are all stored as config files in `~/.config/` or `~/.<software-name>`

So if you copy over your home directory, or at least that (hidden) folder, you should see most(all?) your settings restored

Comment: No, not all settings are restored. A lot may be missing. `~/.config/` contains data from "modern, well behaved" programs. Examples of programs storing their configuration elsewhere: vim, Skype,  mpd, ssh, and many more. Look for directories like `~/.vim` etc.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel, thats why I said to copy the whole home directory

Comment: Oh, sorry - seems like I only read the first and last line.  Copying the home directory completely would work, right.  Or just all hidden directories  and hidden files.

Answer (score 3):

`tar` is your friend.

I recently updated from mint 17.3 to 18.2 and I wanted it to be as smooth as a transition as possible and it was thanks to `tar`.

1. Create a backup of your home directory

   - `tar -cvf home_backup.tar ~/*`
   - `~/*` is all the files in your home directory
2. Put the tarball on a separate drive or machine
3. Extract the tarball right ontop of your home directory (in new machine)

   - `cd ~`
   - `tar -xf home_backup.tar`

Comment: Yep! Its pretty amaizing right? All settings inside that! power of linux!

Answer (score 0):

My anwer is **restricted** to a certain Desktop Manager: it concerns XFCE.

### Saving all XFCE Desktop settings

The settings of the XFCE Manager are at `/home/<user_name>/.config/xfce4/`. Therefore, if you copy the whole directory and then transfer it into a fresh XFCE installation it should work. I guess that for other Desktop Managers (such as Gnome or Unity) an analogous directory must exist.

### Saving only XFCE Desktop Panels

That said, if you were only concerned with thee *GUI panels*, again in XFCE, you can back them up through the GUI. Do as follows:

1. Go to the panel and right click with the mouse on it: *Panel > Panel Preferences*
   [image]
2. Click on *Backup and restore*. There you can save the current configuration in the path you indicate or load a stored backup. Per default the backups are stored in `/home/<your user>/.local/share/xfpanel-switch/`

   [image]

I hope it help someone.